# Is resource trading in Endless Space a flat fee or a per-turn thing?

Tags: endless-space

In Endless Space, Dust can be traded on a *per turn* and *one time* basis. It's never explicitly stated which of those resource trading is.

On a related note, what is your strategic reserve of a resource? Is it a supply that fills up? Is it a throughput rate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Resources exist in fixed, finite amounts.

So it makes more sense to think of it as a "Per Turn" agreement.

For instance, if you agree to trade one Orichalcix for 500 Dust, you agree to pay 500 Dust *now* for ongoing use of that one unit of Orichalcix. If the deal is broken (such as by war), you lose access to that Orichalcix, but you do not gain your money back.